# GNOME keyring daemon sometimes not asking for passphrase, need to provide it via command line

Tags: ssh, password, gnome-keyring

I use a CentOS 7.5 machine, set up with pubkey authentication to ssh to remote servers. Normally, as soon as I ssh to the first server, I get a GNOME graphical prompt asking to type my passphrase to unlock the secret key, so it is not asked anymore during the GNOME session.

However, sometimes I get asked for the passphrase directly in the terminal:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/dr01/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

This is annoying as then I would have to type the passphrase every time I connect to a server. Therefore, in these cases I simply reboot the machine.

---

The GNOME Keyring daemon runs at boot as `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11`.

Restarting it has no effect:

```
[dr01@centos7 ~]$ /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon -r 
** Message: Replacing daemon, using directory: /run/user/1001/keyring
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1001/keyring
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh
```

as afterwards it still asks for the private key's password in the command line.

I've also tried to restart it with

```
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon -r --unlock
```

but it hangs. A `strace` prints this:

```
(...)
read(3, "\335{\232\316.\353\335\22\16\277\321\f\326A\334\272\2\342\227\246V`\262\265\300\213@\273>%\303\2"..., 120) = 120
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 2440}, ru_stime={0, 7321}, ...}) = 0
times({tms_utime=0, tms_stime=0, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 429541253
futex(0x7f0889a5e548, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f088aa6a000
mmap(NULL, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f088aa66000
mlock(0x7f088aa66000, 16384)            = 0
read(0,
```

and it freezes after the `read(0,`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You're using the CentOS 7.x box as the GUI to SSH into other boxes, right?

Comment: @slm Yes, via gnome-terminal-server.

Answer (score 2):

When the passphrase prompt appears in the terminal, it probably means the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable has not been passed to the `ssh` command in that context.

When using the GNOME keyring daemon as a SSH agent (or, indeed, any SSH agent), then the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable should point to a UNIX socket which is created by either the SSH agent program (the GNOME keyring daemon in your case) or `sshd`, if you're working through a SSH connection and agent connection forwarding is enabled.

In other words, perhaps you've done something that causes the user environment to be reset. Perhaps you've used `sudo` and the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is not on the list of environment variables `sudo` is allowed to preserve? Or perhaps you're running the shell escape function of some other program, and that program does not pass the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable through to the shell it runs?

Comment: The `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable exists and is set to a socket file `/tmp/ssh-AlrHnqy0e5iD/agent.1546`, but ssh always asks for the key passphrase in the terminal.  The process with PID 1546 is `/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --session gnome-classic`.

Comment: That looks like a path for `ssh-agent`, not `gnome-keyring-daemon`. Do you have an `ssh-agent` process running as well?