# How to force gnome-keyring-daemon to ask for my passphrase

Tags: ssh, password, gnome-keyring

This is a follow-up to this question: [GNOME keyring daemon sometimes not asking for passphrase, need to provide it via command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460237/gnome-keyring-daemon-sometimes-not-asking-for-passphrase)

Is there a command to force the `gnome-keyring-daemon` to ask for my passphrase for my private key(s), without logging in to any SSH server?

Answer (score 2):

If you have `ssh-askpass` installed (or a variant like `seahorse-ssh-askpass`), you can force a prompt by adding your key to the keyring with `ssh-add`. Note that to get a graphical/UI prompt, you need to disable standard input, because `ssh-add` will read input from the connected terminal if it is available.

```
# will use SSH_ASKPASS, or ssh-askpass by default
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa </dev/null

# use seahorse's prompt utility
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa </dev/null
```

Note that `seahorse` itself provides a UI for managing secrets backed by `gnome-keyring-daemon`, but the main program is not meant for a one-shot prompt-and-save operation.

Comment: What on Earth does SSH have to do with this? My understanding is that the GNOME keyring is a completely abstract secret store. Why is the name of a specific application (ssh) even present in this answer?